# Seemingly redundant conditionals...or not?

Tags: c#

I'm working on some code that has the following pattern of conditionals inside it. It doesn't look great, but it doesn't look terrible.

Please, shed some light on the underlying reason this is not passing my smell test. I'd love to see some alternatives. I'm guessing it's because it's completely ignoring a certain permutation.

Note: I'm asking this question with the intent of bettering the code, not code golf.

```
public class RoleManager
{
    public string Role { get; private set; }

    internal void SetRole(bool isManager, bool hasBackendAccess)
    {
        if (isManager && hasBackendAccess)
        {
            Role = "FullAccess";
        }
        else if (isManager)
        {
            Role = "Manager";
        }
        else if (hasBackendAccess)
        {
            Role = "LimitedBackend";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This still looks hypothetical.  It would be best to post the actual code.

Comment: Yeah, I can't really do that. But watch what happens when I rename the variables.

Comment: How is the resulting `Role` value used? What checks do you run on it? I am suspecting that there might be more smells there.

Comment: It's not about the names, it's about *what problem is this code solving*, so that we know what the *context* is.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg  The role is set in DAL/internal code in the same assembly and then used in comparisons on frontend code when checking permissions.

Comment: And exactly what permission checks do you do? Do you perhaps at any time do `if (Role == "FullAccess" || Role == "Manager")` or something of that kind?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg yes, that's the implication in the code.

Comment: Then your code smell is bigger than just this part of the code. Can you provide some more code context of when you do those permission checks?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg The smell I'm talking about which led me to post the question is with the conditionals. I am actually not concerned that it's not using an enum or that it's a void method with side effects, though they are fair critiques. The conditionals look redundant to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 3 different role values and 1 for not assigning anything, so you'll somehow need 4 discrete values to differentiate. But you could rewrite as:

```
if (isManager)
    Role = hasBackendAccess ? "FullAccess" : "Manager";
else if (hasBackendAccess)
    Role = "LimitedBackend";
```

Comment: That's it. I prefer not to write void methods that change class variables so I've forgotten the magic of how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably nest this a little bit, maybe something like this

```
public class RoleManager
{
    public string Role { get; private set; }

    internal void SetRole(bool isManager, bool hasBackendAccess)
    {
        if (isManager)
        {
            if (hasBackendAccess)
            {
                Role = "FullAccess";
            }
            else 
            {
                Role = "Manager";
            }
        }
        else if (hasBackendAccess)
        {
            Role = "LimitedBackend";
        }
    }
}
```

but I feel that something is missing, what if the user is not a manager or backend user?  what if they are a normal user?  I think that you need a regular user role otherwise you will end up with a null Role.  This could be remedied by setting a default Role to start out with.

Comment: Yeah, that's much better.

Comment: I also like how this doesn't mess with the execution of the method.

Comment: I prefer this over JuniorCompressor's answer, because it's "easier" to read. There's no need to stop and think about the operators that are happening.  This is more how business app's usually look, in my experience.

Comment: I think they're both acceptable for this case since it's rather simple. I think figuring out when you've overcondensed something with ternaries is more of a thing you have to go by feel on anyway.